# C# Reflection: How to search assembly and get generic types

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have different audittrail factories for different events:

```
DomainEventA: DomainEvent
DomainEventB: DomainEvent
```

...

How can I iterate over each event deriving from `DomainEvent`
and check if I have a `AuditTrailFactory` of `T`?

```
 foreach (var type in typeof(DomainEvent).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => !x.IsAbstract && x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(DomainEvent))))
            {
                Assert.NotNull(AuditTrailFactoryProvider.GetAuditTrailFactory<T>());
            }
```

Comment: so you want to invoke `AuditTrailFactoryProvider.GetAuditTrailFactory` with a type parameter that is the `type` in your `foreach` ?

Comment: yes exactly....

Comment: well I still do not know how to do that..